# "your partner's name" or "your partners' name" when there could be one or more partners?

Tags: grammatical-number, apostrophe, saxon-genitive

I am teaching a class that has been grouped, each with one or more partners. I have written on the board to be sure that they write "their partner's name" on their handout. I am unsure where to put the apostrophe in partner's, as it is ambiguous to whether it is plural (partners') or not (partner's).

Where should it go?

Edit: Also, I should note, that there is only one group with more than one partner. All the rest are groups of two.

Comment: If each individual has one *or more* partners, then you want to write *partners'*.  If it matters at all, of course.

Comment: If there's only one partner then it's *partner's*.  If more than one then *partners'*.  If some have a single partner and some multiple then you'd generally use *partners'*.

Comment: But I think if you put it in a plural form - `partners'` - then you need to write `names` instead of `name`.

Comment: "name/s of your partner/s". Or "partner's name / partners' names". Any fudge to try to make apostrophe rules work here will be just that.

Comment: *...the name of each of your partners* should cover it. It does not imply that there is going to be more than one, though that might be an inference someone could draw.

Answer (score 0):

I agree with Edwin Ashworth's advice from 18 moths ago (in a comment above) that the simplest way to make the instruction clear to everyone is to dispense with the apostrophe altogether and frame the instruction as follows:

> Be sure to write the name[s] of your partner[s] on your handout.

Any attempt to produce a universally valid instruction with a sentence using apostrophes is going to lead you into a longer-winded construction like this one:

> Be sure to write your partner's name (or partners' names, as the case may be) on your handout.